# Sum Columns in ListView WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, csv, listview

I have the below csv file:

```
Name,Score
Kelly,5
James,5
Sara,1
Kelly,4
James,1
John,3
```

And I am trying to read the CSV file, get the sum of the Scores based on the Names and load them into the listview.

As a start, I was able to read the CSV file and load it into two listviews for each column. below is my code:

```
   public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();      
        using (var fs = File.OpenRead(filepath))
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(fs))
        {
            List<string> list0 = new List<string>();
            List<string> list1 = new List<string>();
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = reader.ReadLine();
                var values = line.Split(',');

                list0.Add(values[0]);
                list1.Add(values[1]);
                 //sum = list1.Sum(x => Convert.ToInt32(x));
            }

            List0.ItemsSource = list0;
            List1.ItemsSource = list1; 

         }
  }
```

and here's the xaml code I used:

```
    <ListView Name="List0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="258" Margin="0,33,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="267" >
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <ListView Name="List1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="258"   Margin="272,33,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="172" >
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

And this is working fine with me. But I got stuck from here and I was wondering if it's possible to get the sum of the Score column based on the Names in the listview.

For example, get the total score of Kelly, get the total score of James etc. So the listview would look like this:

```
Name,Score
Kelly,9 
James,6 
Sara,1
John,3
```

I tried to use the Sum option and thought of printing it to a label to test, but it didn't work and i got an error saying "Input string was not in a correct format"

I am still not that experienced in C#, WPF and XAML; especially in reading and parsing CSV files so I am not sure how to go about this. Any help in this matter or pointers is much appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a new class for storing the persons including their score.
Something like this

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }

    public Person(string name, int score)
    {
        Name = name;
        Score = Score;
    }
}
```

Then you could change your logic to something like this

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filepath);
var persons = new List<Person>();

foreach(var line in lines)
{
    var values = line.Split(',');
    var name = values[0];
    var score = int.Parse(line[1].ToString());

    var person = persons.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == name);
    if(person == null)
    {
        var newPerson = new Person(name, score);
        persons.Add(newPerson);
    }
    else
    {
        person.Score += score;
    }
}
```

Advantage of a Person class is a cleaner and more understandable code; no magic strings where nobody knows what their value means.

In your logic you can raise the score of a person when you already have one entry for the person in your list.

//edit Binding to xaml
You can use a `DataGrid` for example.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" />
```

Persons is the `ObservableCollection<Person>` in your ViewModel. The `DataGrid` will automatically create one column for every property in your Person class.
You could custommize your `DataGrid` to get the look you want. There are alot of examples in the internet.

//edit Binding
The collection with the persons has to be public. Otherwise you could not access it from the xaml.

You could remove

```
var persons = new List<Person>();
```

And replace it with a property in your MainWindow class.

```
public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons {get; set;}
```

You class should look like

```
public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons {get; set;}

public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filepath);
        Persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
```

And in your `DataGrid` change the binding to `ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}"`

Comment: Thanks @Mighty Badaboom I will try your answer. But can you please explain what FirstOrDefault means? Also, how can bind this to the list view that I have? Thanks again

Comment: FirstOrDefault will give you the first match. If no item is matching you'll get null. Have a look at https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b to get familiar with LINQ. It's very usefull.

When binding to your xaml I would use an ObservableCollection<Person> instead of a List<T>. How do you want to display your data? Guess a DataGrid would be a good choice. Bind your Person to the ItemsSource of the DataGrid. If you have problems post your code and I can help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Currently I storing the CSV file into a list and displaying it in a listview. But I am not sure if I am doing this right because I have two listviews and each column is in a different listview. Is this the right approach?

Comment: That isn't a good approach because you are storing depending data in two different controls. Give me a minute  and I change my post to give you an example.

Comment: Edited my post for a short example.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your short example and for your explanation. I will give it a try now. Just one more question, do i need to bind the Person class in my MainWindow() as the itemsource for the datagrid? Or is it not needed since it's already done in XAML? Thanks again!

Comment: Not needed when you did it in the XAML (which is the best and cleanest way). Another hint: When you've done it you should have a look at the MVVM pattern. It's 'the' pattern for developing WPF applications.

Comment: Awesome! I will try this and take a look at the MVVM. Thank you so much for your great help and for being patient with me!! :)

Comment: Your welcome. If it's working I would thank you for accepting my answer and/or upvoting it.
Good luck and enjoy WPF ;)

Comment: It seems I will still need your help :) I just tried it. and it ran with no errors but the datagrid is empty and not showing any data. I will post my code to show you if it's okay

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. For updating your answer. I have never used observablecollection before so I am a bit confused as to why did we need to create a class called Person, then the observablecollection Persons, and then using Persons again in this line: var person = Persons.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == name); ?

Comment: ObservableCollection is because it's implementing INotifyProperyChange to update your view when changes happening. The class Person is for one person. You have x persons, thats why you need a collection to store them. In the quoted line you check if a Person with the same name already existing. If yes you can increment her score. If not you create a new Person and put it in the list.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I made the modifications and still nothing is showing in the datagrid. The code seems to be working fine because I ran the code in the debug mode and followed each line to see if the code is actually doing the sum and it is. But it's not being displayed on the datagrid. Maybe the data grid is not "binded" correctly to the data generated?

Comment: Never mind, I got it to work. I thought I would try to bind the datagrid to the results I am getting from **Persons** in my MainWindow(). So I added this line in my MainwWindow(): 
datagrid.ItemsSource = Persons; and this made it work :) 
Thanks a lot for all your help and your clear explanations. You've been very helpful and I got to learn a lot from you :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a Dictionary:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();      
    using (var fs = File.OpenRead(filepath))
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(fs))
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            var values = line.Split(',');

            // Discard header line
            if (("Name" == values[0]) && ("Score" == values[1]))
                continue;

            if (dict.ContainsKey(values[0]))
                dict[values[0]] += Convert.ToInt32(values[1]);
            else
                dict[values[0]] = Convert.ToInt32(values[1]);
        }

        // Now you can create some lists to display
        var list0 = new List<string>();
        var list1 = new List<string>();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in dict)
        {
            list0.Add(entry.Key);
            list1.Add(entry.Value.ToString());
        }

        List0.ItemsSource = list0;
        List1.ItemsSource = list1; 
     }
}
```

Comment: Greetings dumetrulo, thanks for your comment. I will try this, but what are the benefits of using a dictionary?I have never used them before. Thanks!

Comment: I am assuming in the foreach line you meant: foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> entry in dict) not <string, string> right?

Comment: I would use a class instead of KeyValuePairs with magic strings. Have a look at my answer for an example.

Comment: I have tried your answer, too and it worked with me as well. I never knew I can use dictionaries in C# so I will read about it. Thanks a lot for your help :)